# Cross Validation using the DAAG package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get the `CVlm` function to work applying the `DAAG` package 
my dataset: fit (has 27 entries (rows) with 6 variables
I use the following expression in R:

```
CrossVal<-CVlm(df=fit,m=3,
form.lm=formula(fit$X1~fit$X2 + fit$X3 + fit$X4 + fit$X5 + fit$X6))
```

when using `m=1` it works nice by for m different from 1 (e.g. 3 as shown above) I get an error message:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rows.out, "cvpred", value = c(228.541323416399,  : 
  replacement has 27 rows, data has 9
In addition: Advarselsbesked:
'newdata' had 9 rows but variable(s) found have 27 rows
```

I would be happy for some help to get the cv to work properly
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please make your situation reproducible, i.e. provide us with the data and the code needed to mimic your situation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example for more tips on how to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Hard to say whithout a reproducible example , But I think you don't write the right formula. This should work for you

```
 CrossVal<-CVlm(df=fit,m=3,
                form.lm= formula(X1 ~ X2 + X3 + X4 + X5 + X6))
```

For example using `housprices` data from `DAAG` I can reproduce the error:

```
 CVlm(df = houseprices, form.lm =
        formula(houseprices$sale.price ~ houseprices$area), m=2)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rows.out, "cvpred", value = c(201.067581902091,  : 
  replacement has 15 rows, data has 7
```

but this works fine :

```
CVlm(df = houseprices, form.lm = formula(sale.price ~ area), m=2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: sale.price
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
area       1  18566   18566       8  0.014 *
```

**EDIT** why m =1 works and not with m different of 1:

Here the part of the code of `CVlm` where the error occurs:

```
subs.lm <- lm(form, data = df[rows.in, ])
df[rows.out, "cvpred"] <- predict(subs.lm, newdata = df[rows.out,
```

The error  occurs because we try to set 9 rows of df with  27 rows.                                                            ])

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, rows.out, "cvpred", value = c(228.541323416399,  : 
  replacement has 27 rows, data has 9
```

indeed `predict` works with the effect side, it don't use the `newdata` object but uses the original data.frame since you give the formula using `$` and this is what it is printed in the warning :

```
In addition: Advarselsbesked:
'newdata' had 9 rows but variable(s) found have 27 rows
```

with m=1 it works because newdata has the same number of rows than the original data set. Of course the result is not correct because it don't use the newdata subset which is permutation of the original one.